# Does 'nie' go to the start of the sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation

Does it count as time?

I am using it in this sentence, "Nie gucke ich fernsehen" or "Ich gucke nie fernsehen" ?

Answer (score 4):

When used at the start of a sentence, it is usually an exaggeration.

"Nie darf ich fernsehen"
"Nie bringst du den Müll raus"

Or:

"Immer bist du betrunken"